# Is there a way to push notification via a chatbot deployed in facebook developed with dialogflow w/ node.js for fulfillment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I'm developing a facebook/workplace chatbot using dialogflow with node.js for fulfillment. Can't seem to find resources for pushing notifications.

I want to be able to trigger sending the message by visiting the webhook url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Facebook Graph APIs to send a facebook notification to a specific user. User can click on the notification to launch the facebook messenger chatbot.

Here is a quick example.

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/{user_id}/notifications?template={your_message}&href={link}&access_token={page_access_token}

You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications/

Basically, you need to run a web service which when called makes the calls to the facebook notification APIs.

All you need to do is pass the user id, the message/link to be displayed in the notification and the page access token.

When someone first sends you a message via Facebook, Facebook provides you the page-specific user id which you can store in the database.

Page access token can be accessed by going to https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: thanks! is that still possible if I used the one click integration to facebook in dialogflow?

Comment: According to this article: https://miningbusinessdata.com/api-ai-push-notifications/ , push notifications don't work in dialogflow. do you agree?

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with Dialogflow api. It uses standard Facebook graph API.

Comment: @n_generot Were you able to solve this? I have a similar use case where I need to send a push notification to a chatbot developed in Dialogflow and integrated with Facebook messeneger

Comment: @James do you want to send the notification to a messenger chatbot or you want to send notification inside the user's Facebook account.

Comment: @Anshul: I would like to send it to the FB messenger chatbot. But on the other hand sending it to the user's FB account is easier, I would like to consider that option as well